# How to create a custom registration page for two step registration of a user in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04LTS and having an environment of vagrant homestead with PHP 7.0 and Laravel 5.3. I have to create a two step registration process for a user. For example on the first page of the form the user will provide his name, email and password like the default registration page and there will be a button of "Next" which will lead to a second form and these fields will be passed on to that second form as hidden fields. From here after completing the second form the user will click on the "Register" button and this will add the first form details to the Users table in the default user migration, while the form filled on the second page will add all of those details to a different table including this currently created user's user_id so that later on we can have an eloquent relationship between both of these tables.

What I have done is that I have create a new controller where I'm having constructor that will allow this custom signup page and the second form page as exception. Then there will be a form which is a copy of the default registration page and this signup form will submit the values which a method in controller called "Signup" will handle and it will accept all of these values and pass them on to the second form and in the second form I'm fetching all of these values in hidden input fields. Then in the same custom controller I got another method called "create" this method is handling all the requests received in through this form. Then first I'm saving all of these fields into relevant variables and later I'm creating a new User instance like this:

```
$name = $request->name;
$email = $request->email;
$password = $request->password;

$user = new User();
$user->name = $name;
$user->email = $email;
$user->password = bcrypt($password);
```

And now once this user is created in the database I'm storing the other fields of the second form into relevant variables just like above example and later on I'm creating a new instance for the other migration where I want to save the values in the second_form table.

Now so far, everything is working fine and all of the values are being stored in the database. The problem comes here that once the user clicks on the "Register" button he is directed to the newly created welcome page, but he is still not logged in. He needs to login again from the above given login link (I have only changed the default Register to Signup and left the "Login" as it is).

Can anyone guide me if there is any other way or best practice through which I can achieve the same objective of two step registration form?

Regards, Mohsin.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually authenticate created user:

```
Auth::login($user); // Login given user
Auth::login($user, true); // Login and remember the given user
```

> If you need to log an existing user instance into your application, you may call the `login` method with the user instance.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: When the second_form is saved in the database before calling the welcome view if I try to instantiate Auth then I am getting a null value, for example:

$auth = new Auth();

Answer (score 0):

I am explaining the method which I used in one of my project where I had multiple pages before registration.

There from the first page the values passed are kept inside the session. Then the next page will take additional information. When the user clicks on the register button, I will insert the data into the table.

Make sure to use `Auth::login($user)` to login the current user after saving the values in db and redirect to the dashboard

Comment: This is returning null if I call it before returning the view:
$auth = new Auth();
        $auth = Auth::login($user);
        dd($auth);

Comment: you have to call this after saving the things to database and then call this function. After that redirect to the dashboard.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm doing, like I have saved both instances in the database for form 1 to users table and form 2 to second_form table. After that I'm calling the Auth::login($user) and it is returning me null.